# What is the logic behind Java's forcing you to provide no-arg constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

In other words, what would be the problem if Java compiler provided a default constructor, even in the case when there also is a constructor with args?

Comment: You don't *have to* provide a no-arg constructor.

Comment: @assylias You do if you only provide a constructor that has arguments, and someone tries to create an instance of your class using a no-argument constructor.

Comment: @FredK You still don't *have* to define one.. let them get a compile error for using your class incorrectly. *Not* defining a no-arg constructor is completely valid.

Comment: @xtratic True, but the OP was asking WHY doesn't the compiler automatically provide a no-argument constructor when you provide a constructor with arguments. The answer is precisely  what you point out: If I don't want to allow a no-arg constructor, it would be impossible to do  if the compiler automatically provided one.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, Java will provide a no-arg constructor if none is provided.

If you have an "arg" constructor and don't try to use the no-arg constructor (or define one) you have no problem.

However, the **Java Serialization library requires you to have a no-arg constructor** so it knows how to create an object when it is deserialized.

An alternative which I take with my library is to call the no-arg constructor if it exists, or just create the object without calling a constructor if it doesn't.  This can the side effect that fields are not initialised if you don't call a constructor. e.g.

```
class MyClass {
    // only set if you call a constructor!
    transient final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int a;

    MyClass(int a) { this.a = a; }
}
```

In this situation, not having a no-arg constructor means it is hard to know how to deserialize it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> ...even in the case when there also is a constructor with args?

Then there'd be no way for you to prevent your class from having a no-args constructor other than declaring a private one (which isn't quite the same as it not having one).

Having only a constructor accepting arguments is a common use case. Making you declare a private no-args constructor in that common case wouldn't make much sense.

In contrast, wanting to have **no** constructors for a class is an uncommon use case. So providing one when you don't provide any explicitly makes (some) sense (though frankly I'd be just as happy if it didn't provide a default at all).

Comment: There's no way to prevent your class from having any constructor, other than declaring a private one.

Comment: @shmosel - I said that above. I'm not sure what you're clarifying...

Comment: You said there'd be no way to prevent a class from having a no-arg constructor. I'm pointing out that there are cases where you don't want a constructor at all, and there's no way around that other than declaring a private constructor.

Comment: @shmosel - I said that in my last paragraph.

Comment: .........indeed